# Tkinter - Creating multiple check boxes using a loop

Tags: python, tkinter

I am trying to create a program that allows the user to select any number of check boxes and hit a button to return a random result from those check boxes. Since I am basing my list off the roster of Smash bros ultimate, I am trying to avoid creating 70+ variables just to place check boxes. However, I am unable to figure out how to iterate this. The various values set for rows are just placeholders until I can figure this out. I would also like to have a reset button at the top that allows the user to automatically uncheck every box. This code is what I have so far. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

from tkinter import *
window = Tk()

#window name and header
window.title("Custom Random SSBU")
lbl = Label(window, text="Select the fighters you would like to include:")
lbl.grid(column=1, row=0)

f = [] #check boxes

ft = open("Fighters.txt").readlines() #list of all the character names

fv=[0]*78 #list for tracking what boxes are checked

ff=[] #list to place final character strings

def  reset():
   for i in fv:
       fv[i]=0

rst = Button(window, text="Reset", command=reset)
rst.grid(column=0, row=3)

for y in range (0,77):
    f[y] = Checkbutton(window, text = ft[y], variable = fv[y])
    f[y].grid(column=0, row=4+y)

def done():
    for j in fv:
        if fv[j] == 1:
            ff.append(fv[j])
    result = random.choice(ff)
    r=Label(window, text=result)

d = Button(window, text="Done", command=done)
d.grid(column=0, row = 80)

window.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately I'm afraid you *are* going to have to create variables for each checkbox.

`tkinter` has special purpose [Variable Classes](https://effbot.org/tkinterbook/variable.htm) for holding different types of values, and if you specify an instance of one as the `variable=` option when you create widgets like `Checkbutton`, it will automatically set or reset its value whenever the user changes it, so all your program has to do is check its current value by calling its `get()` method.

Here's an example of the modifications to your code needed to create them in a loop (and use them in the `done()` callback function):

```
import random
from tkinter import *

window = Tk()

#window name and header
window.title("Custom Random SSBU")

lbl = Label(window, text="Select the fighters you would like to include:")
lbl.grid(column=1, row=0)

with open("Fighters.txt") as fighters:
    ft = fighters.read().splitlines() # List of all the character names.

fv = [BooleanVar(value=False) for _ in ft] # List to track which boxes are checked.

ff = [] # List to place final character strings.

def  reset():
   for var in fv:
       var.set(False)

rst = Button(window, text="Reset", command=reset)
rst.grid(column=0, row=3)

for i, (name, var) in enumerate(zip(ft, fv)):
    chk_btn = Checkbutton(window, text=name, variable=var)
    chk_btn.grid(column=0, row=i+4, sticky=W)

def done():
    global ff
    ff = [name for name, var in zip(ft, fv) if var.get()]  # List of checked names.
    # Randomly select one of them.
    choice.configure(text=random.choice(ff) if ff else "None")

d = Button(window, text="Done", command=done)
d.grid(column=0, row=len(ft)+4)

choice = Label(window, text="None")
choice.grid(column=1, row=3)

window.mainloop()
```

I wasn't sure where you wanted the `Label` containing the result to go, so I just put it to the right of the <kbd>Reset</kbd> button.

Answer (score 1):

```
variable = fv[y]
```

This looks up the value of `fv[y]` - i.e, the integer `0` - at the time the Checkbutton is created, and uses that for the `variable` argument.

You need to use an instance of one of the [value-tracking classes provided by TKinter](https://effbot.org/tkinterbook/variable.htm), instead. In this case we want `BooleanVar` since we are tracking a boolean state. We can still create these in a list ahead of time:

```
text = open("Fighters.txt").readlines()
# Let's not hard-code the number of lines - we'll find it out automatically,
# and just make one for each line.
trackers = [BooleanVar() for line in text]
# And we'll iterate over those pair-wise to make the buttons:
buttons = [
    Checkbutton(window, text = line, variable = tracker)
    for line, tracker in zip(text, trackers)
]
```

(but we can *not* do, for example `trackers = [BooleanVar()] * len(text)`, because that gives us the *same* tracker 78 times, and thus every checkbox will share that tracker; we need to track each separately.)

When you click the checkbox, TKinter will automatically update the internal state of the corresponding `BooleanVar()`, which we can check using its `.get()` method. Also, when we set up our options for `random.choice`, we want to choose the corresponding text for the button, not the tracker. We can do this with the `zip` trick again.

So we want something more like:

```
result_label = Label(window) # create it ahead of time

def done():
    result_label.text = random.choice(
        label
        for label, tracker in zip(text, trackers)
        if tracker.get()
    )
```